# how to configure database connection on the fly with persistence

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jdbc, persistence

I set up database connection in persistence.xml including server url and username/password. However, if I want to switch between development environment (dev/qa/stg/prod) is there a better way to change the configuration instead of manually modify persistence.xml?

I am using jdbc connection to call stored procedure together with hibernate stuff. The jdbc connection is more flexible. It connects to different database depending on an environment variable DEV_ENV.

```
// DEV DB
if (env.equalsIgnoreCase("dev")) {
    connectionURL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@ldap://mdaoid.mdanderson.org:389/risdev3, cn=OracleContext,dc=mdacc,dc=tmc,dc=edu";
    user = "ristore_owner";
    pass = "ristoreowner987";
}
// QA DB
else if (env.equalsIgnoreCase("qa")) {
    connectionURL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@ldap://mdaoid.mdanderson.org:389/risdev3, cn=OracleContext,dc=mdacc,dc=tmc,dc=edu";
    user = "ristore_owner_qa";
    pass = "ristore987q";
}
```

How do I configure hibernate db connection in the same way, pick up environment variable and decide which db to connect to on the fly?

EDIT: People showed me how to do it with a war which picks up the db information from tomcat server. However, mine is a java application (jar) which I don't deploy. I set it up as a cron job to run the jar on weekly basis.

Comment: why manually modify persistence.xml? you can have 2 persistence-units "dev" and "prod" and create your EMF with whichever is appropriate

Comment: @NeilStockton Haven't thought about using units. Will give it a try. Where and how should I create my EMF though?

Comment: Where and how do you create your EMF now??

Comment: @NeilStockton sorry that was a silly question. I think it should work. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create two xml config files. 
   persistenceDev.xml and persistenceQA.xml
2. Add url, user, and password for each environment.
3. Then user SessionFactory to create sessions

Note: The only thing you change is the config file name. 
I would provide is a command line argument or a static final variable. 
Say, assuming 0 = dev, 1 = qa.

```
String configFileName = (args[0] == 0) ? persistenceDev.xml: persistenceQA.xml;
```

Your code after getting the config file does not change.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you provide the environment somehow. My suggestion is to use a build tool (like Maven, Gradle, etc.) through which you can give as arguments the actual environment like UAT, Dev, Prod.

Then you can have multiple configuration files like application-dev.xml, application-uat.xml. During build you use the build tool to load the approppiate configuration file.

As a reference for doing this in Maven you can have a look [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-for-different-environments.html).